# Array with tricky duplication

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I was using the PHP function [parse_ini_file()](http://www.php.net/parse_ini_file) to build an array structure from a INI File I have, but I was somewhat forced to create a custom parser because the native function has no support for nested files nor it parses the file comments.

Although a real INI files do not support complex hierarchy, with such feature I could easily manipulate other informations I have (or so I hope).

And the possibility to have the comments in the file is not really a requirement, but if I allow the INI file to be edited through a GUI, if I don't have access to them the resulting file would not make much sense.

And this "not required requirement" is the problem I can't solve.

Right... I'm publishing the class (and a supporting interface) in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daa65d856e5e25d162cc) because it's a little big.

> Do not judge the method *Reader::process()* too hard because this is not the real class. The real one involves an entire Stream Reader that would just complicate things if posted here. That fragment, however, is a valid replacement.

The INI File I'm using for testing purposes is this one:

```
[info]
; Comment Section 1: author
author="Bruno Augusto"
; Comment Section 1: copyright
copyright="MIT"

[descriptor]
; Comment Section 2: name
name="Item Name"
; Comment Section 2: description
description="Item Description"
; Comment Section 2: Line 1
; Comment Section 2, Line 2 (version)
version=1.0

[contents]
; Comment Section 3: Line 1
; Comment Section 3, Line 2 (files)
files[] = config.ini
files[] = folder/file1.php
files[] = folder/folder2/file2.php
files[] = folder/folder2/folder3/file3.php
files[] = folder/folder2/folder3/file4.php

[hierarchyTest]
; Comment Section 4: levels
levels[first\second\third] = "foo"
levels[first\second\third] = "anotherone"
levels[first\second\third] = "onemore"
levels[first\second\third\fourth] = "bar"
levels[first\second\third\fourth] = "baaz"

[hierarchyTest2]
; Comment Section 5: Line 1
; Comment Section 5, Line 2 (levels2)
levels2[first.second.third] = "baaz"
```

The usage is as simple as instantiate the Reader class with the path of the INI file and invoke the *Reader::read()* method. We're all big boys here, I think I can suppress this. :p

The buggy comments are proccesed starting in line [68](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daa65d856e5e25d162cc#file-gistfile1-txt-L68) and added to the final structure in line [81](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daa65d856e5e25d162cc#file-gistfile1-txt-L81)*.

The problem is that currently all the values are being accumulated after each iteration. The one to blame is the array_merge() used in line [69](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daa65d856e5e25d162cc#file-gistfile1-txt-L69). By removing it:

```
$comments = $line;
```

Almost everything works fine, except that multi-line comments holds only the last line as expected by a direct assignment.

Initially, I thought I could simply empty the array after use it so I've added such instruction in the line [84](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daa65d856e5e25d162cc#file-gistfile1-txt-L84):

```
$comments = array();
```

And here is the weirdness. It works well for almost all entries, but the sections named **contents** and **hierarchyTest** have no comments added.

I've isolated the problem and it's because of the hierarchy parsing, starting at line [92](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daa65d856e5e25d162cc#file-gistfile1-txt-L92) but I have no idea how to solve this.

This isolation is so true that if I add one more entry to the last section (hierarchyTest2) with the format:

```
levels2[first.second.third] = "baazaaa"
```

Its comments vanishes too.

Comment: This is a well worded question. I don't immediately have an answer for you, but can you use XML instead of an INI? This might give you more flexibility to parse comments and nested functionality.

Comment: Just PHP arrays, XML or even JSON would be much better suited to this I would say.  Easier to read/change/write.

Comment: I would be lying if I told you this idea didn't come to my mind and, in fact, I was wondering, I think I'll use XML or JSON in the final product, yes, but I'm so puzzled with this situation... I mean, I spent the whole afternoon trying everything I could and nothing worked. It's almost a matter of honor, you know.